# Incomplete Safe Object after Gnosis Safe deployment via SDK

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I am currently working on an **OpenZeppelin Defender AutoTask** script (which is in JS), making use of the [safe-core-sdk](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/safe-core-sdk).

The basics are working, I have successfully deployed a Safe via this script on Goerli via the official Factory, so that part is fine. However, I am a bit confused as the [resulting `Safe` object](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/a8d5494daed4672e3980097a4b8cd8aaf9a2b835/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/safeFactory/index.ts#L245) that I am receiving via the `safeFactory.deploySafe(...)` call seems to be incomplete somehow.

The implementation used in the SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/Safe.ts), where you can see that it should contain functions like `getAddress()` or `createAddOwnerTx()`. While the read-only ones seem to work (I can use `getAddress()` and so on), the other ones (like `createAddOwnerTx()`) are all leading to an error of `... is not a function`. Printing `createdSafe` via `console.log()` just gives me `Safe { }`.

I have already tried to `create` a new safeSDK (a `Safe` instance) from scratch based on the deployed safe, but the same thing happens here. I am not really sure what to do here, what am I missing? Any ideas?

```js
// Note: some of this code is related to the openzeppelin defender
const { DefenderRelayProvider } = require('defender-relay-client/lib/web3');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Safe = require('@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk');
const { SafeFactory, SafeAccountConfig, Web3Adapter } = require('@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk');

exports.handler = async function(credentials) {
  const defenderProvider = new DefenderRelayProvider(credentials, { speed: 'fastest' });
  const web3 = new Web3(defenderProvider);

  const signer = '0x<REMOVED>';

  const ethAdapter = new Web3Adapter({
    web3,
    signerAddress: signer
  });
  
  const owners = ['0x<REMOVED>'];
  const threshold = 1;
  const safeAccountConfig = {
    owners,
    threshold
  };
  
  const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter });

  // note: this works fine, the deployed safe is correct and working
  const createdSafe = await safeFactory.deploySafe(safeAccountConfig);

  const safeAddress = await createdSafe.getAddress();
  console.log(safeAddress); // this works!

  // the following does not work (error: createAddOwnerTx is not a function)
  const addUserTx = await safeSdk3.createAddOwnerTx({ ownerAddress: '0x<REMOVED>' });
  const addUserTxResponse = await safeSdk3.executeTransaction(createdTx);
}
```